# Making a div dissapear after 5 seconds, validation error message

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a div called ".error" which appears if an registration form is submitted and it has errors, it doesn't appear otherwise. I am trying to make a javascript statement incorporating jquery which uses an if structure.

```
For example

if error div is visible after submit button is clicked

remove the error div after several seconds

end if statement
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

***Edit:*** Here is my actual code, I have tried implementing some of the examples provided but none have worked thus far.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var hideError = function () {
   $(".error").hide();
};

$("registration-form").submit(function () {
    setTimeout(hideError, 5000);
});

});
</script>

<?php
   $validation_errors = '';
   $proc_errors = '';
   if (isset($_POST['register'])) { // User submitted registration form
   require_once "formvalidator.php";
   $validator = new FormValidator();
   $validator->addValidation("new-username","req","Please enter a username");
   $validator->addValidation("new-username","minlen=5","Username cannot be less than 5           characters");
   $validator->addValidation("new-username","maxlen=25","Username cannot be more than 25 characters");
   $validator->addValidation("new-username","alpha","Username must not contain spaces, numbers or strange characters");

   $validator->addValidation("new-password","req","Please enter a password");
   $validator->addValidation("new-password","minlen=5","Password must be at least 5 characters!");
   $validator->addValidation("new-password","maxlen=25","Password cannot be more than 25 characters");

   $validator->addValidation("new-password2","eqelmnt=new-password","The confirmation password does not match");
   $validator->addValidation("new-password2","req","Please enter the confirm password field");

   $validator->addValidation("email","email","Please enter a valid e-mail address");
   $validator->addValidation("email","req","Please enter a valid e-mail address");

   $validator->addValidation("forename","req","Please enter your forename");

   $validator->addValidation("surname","req","Please enter your surname");

   $validator->addValidation("securityquestion","dontselect=--Select One--","Please choose a security question");

   $validator->addValidation("securityanswer","req","Please enter a security answer");
   $validator->addValidation("securityanswer","minlen=5","Security answer must be more than 4 characters");

   if($validator->ValidateForm()) {
    //If the validations succeeded, proceed with form processing
    $formproc = new regProcessor();
    $res = $formproc->ProcessForm();
    if($res == "SUCCESS") {
        header("Location: registrationsuccess.php"); /* Redirect browser */
        exit();
    } else {
        $proc_errors = '<div class="error">'.$res.'</div>';
    }
   } else {
    //Validations failed. Display Errors.
    $error_hash = $validator->GetErrors();
    $validation_errors = '';
    foreach($error_hash as $inpname => $inp_err) {
       $validation_errors .= '<div class="error">'.$inp_err.'</div>';
    }
  }
 }
?>
```

Comment: I appreciate all the feedback, I will have a go with what has been said, the divs are being generated with PHP, they don't pre-exist on the HTML.

Comment: If the divs are being generated by PHP (i.e. on the server) doesn't this mean that they exist when the page is initially rendered to the browser?

Comment: See, thats what I thought too which has led me going this method of removing it. The code three quarters down the php is where the div is being made, it begins with if($res=="SUCCESS"){

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To hide the div, create a function such as the one below that uses [jQuery `hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

```
var hideError = function () {
    $(".error").hide();
};
```

(you can safely call this even if the error div is already hidden)

Call it when your form is submitted (with a jQuery `submit` event handler), but after a 5 second delay by means of [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout).

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    setTimeout(hideError, 5000);
});
```

This means that any validation message will be hidden if the user submits the form by clicking the *Submit* button, but also if they do so by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on their keyboard.

Comment: I will give this a blast, it looks very similar to what I am looking

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript's `setTimeout` function, thuswise:

```
setTimeout(function() {
      // remove your error div
}, 5000);
```

Comment: This isn't jQuery function.

Comment: True. Edited to reflect.

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
<div id="message"></div>

<button type="submit" onclick="message();">submit</button>

function message() {

 $('#message').show();
 setTimeout(function() { $('#message').hide(); }, 5000);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    if ($("div").css("visibility","visible")) {
        setTimeout(function(){$("div").css("visibility","hidden")},2000)
    }
})
```

This will work if you have hidden this message using `visibility` if not then change relevant parts accordingly, if you need help just ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more jQuery idiomatic approach, then extent jQuery:

Define an jQuery extension function:

```
$.fn.delayedHide = function(delay) {
  var that = this;
  window.setTimeout(function () {
    that.hide();
  }, delay || 5000);
  return that;
}
```

Now suppose you have the following HTML:

```
<div class="msg">MSG1</div>
<div class="msg msg-err">MSG2 (ERR)</div>
<div class="msg">MSG3</div>
<div class="msg msg-err">MSG4 (ERR)</div>
```

Then you can hide all error messages at once with

```
$(".msg-err").delayedHide();
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/8wh4h/1/

Comment: Of course you can replace the hiding with removing (sry, did forget your exact needings while writing the fiddle ^^)

Comment: Cheers for the full example, much appreciated! The div is being generated by the php after the form is submitted which seems to be causing trouble

Comment: Well, then just combine this solution with the `$("form").submit(function () { /*...*/ });` suggestions from the other answers. What I posted is just some sort of idiomatic improvement over the other solutions here.

Answer (score 0):

For a smooth transition you could use the jQuery [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)/[fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) functions with a delay after fading in.

```
$('.error').fadeIn(600, function() {
    $(this).delay(4000).fadeOut(600);
});
```